# Limit Netflix bandwidth

Tags: router, bandwidth, netflix, traffic-shaping

Netflix massacres my ping whenever I play online games.

Preferably, I'd like to be able to monitor and limit/assign priorities to any applications using my home network, but if it's a Netflix-specific solution, I'll take it. I have no idea where to start, and my Google searches thus far haven't helped.

I have a Linksys E2000 router. Netflix is being used from Xbox, TV app, and computer browsers.

Any tips, especially links to tutorials, etc. would be very helpful.

Comment: Try QoS - http://www.gwi.net/policy/blog/four-steps-to-implementing-quality-of-service-on-your-home-router/  -  It will really only work on traffic on your own network, it won't stay prioritized once it leaves your router, but it will certainly help a little bit.

Comment: Thanks! Haven't tested yet, but it's set up and should work. If you want to make this an answer, I'll mark as correct.